# Any built-in Linux methods for AXI-burst type devices?

Tags: linux, drivers, axi, fpga

I need to communicate with an FPGA device based on an AXI-burst interface. What are the ways to access such a device through Linux without involving a DMA? Burst is an intrinsic property of the AXI standard, which should typically be triggered automatically when large amounts of data are being transferred. And the bigger problem is the FPGA is designed so as to respond only to burst type requests over the AXI bus. So this causes serious issues on Linux when the application tries sequential copy.
P.S. I have already tried memcpy and it doesn't work.

Comment: no takers at all??? I'm surprised and fairly disappointed !

Comment: You might consider asking hardware.stackexchange.com or possibly the LKML (where you'll probably get at least some pointers as to where to go next) - and you might also mention the bounty on here ;). Sorry I don't know myself; I just noticed this post at the top of the list when I visited today :P

Comment: Thanks, which hardware stackexchange? There isn't one by the URL you referred..

Comment: AGH... facepalm moment! I saw http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ when I looked at the SE site grid ages ago, thought "ah, so that's the closest SE currently has to a hardware section", and my memory just saved the bit about SE  having a hardware section! Thankfully I was wrong!! :D - http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/8148/computer-hardware-networking-qa-site (*be sure to read the comment with the network engineering link in it*) :) The worst you risk by posting to all ***3*** mentioned places is closed questions.

Comment: Thanks... I've posted the same on stack overflow. Also mentioned the bounty like you said :P

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming. It would be on-topic on [electronics.se] or on [so] where [it has been reposted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373717/any-built-in-linux-methods-for-axi-burst-type-devices).

Comment: @Gilles - this is NOT about programming. This is specifically about any Linux implementations to handle the AXI layer.

Comment: And this is certainly not "on-topic" on Electrical Engineering. I am asking about how Linux handles AXI, and how I can go about debugging it. I am not asking how to program it, I am not asking for programs.

Comment: Accessing hardware is something you can only do inside the kernel. Writing code inside the kernel is clearly programming! And debugging is equally a programming activity. Furthermore, [we don't want questions posted on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata); since you've reposted on SO (you should have flagged for migration instead, but it's too late now), the question would need to be closed here even if it was also on-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your “FPGA device” is a custom block, memory-mapped over AXI interface to Cortex-A9. I think there are 2 or 3 ways you could make this work.

1) Cacheable mapping. Cache hardware interface does burst-transfer of an entire cache line at a time. You would need to manually clean (after writes) and invalidate (before reads).

2) Non-cacheable mapping, and have an ARM assembly language routine handle the low-level transfer. I think the “Load and Store Multiple registers” instructions can provide what you are looking for.

I had a similar problem where an AXI peripheral (custom memory controller) needed to be accessed with 8-byte transfers from Cortex-A9 processor. The usual ARM instructions, of course, transfer 1, 2, or 4 bytes (byte, halfword, word). Those worked through cacheable mapping, but not through non-cacheable mapping. [LDM/STM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihcadda.html), 2 words at a time, worked with both mappings.

AHB/AXI transfer modes are implementation dependent, of course. Per your description, you need INCR or WRAP modes rather than SINGLE. But it should not have to be that way. That brings up the third way you could make this work:

3) Talk with your digital hardware designer, make him aware of the software impact of his implementation.

In my opinion, you shouldn’t have to do unusual / custom low-level MMU operations. Linux has high-level methods, you would put standard hooks in your device driver and/or board.c, the main option is whether to go uncached (i.e. COHERENT). Refer to [LDD3](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/?u=chp-15-sect-4).